# save Excel file with epPlus

Tags: vb.net, uwp, epplus

I have a problem when save an Excel file in UWP app (Windows Template):

```
        Dim excel As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()

        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1")
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 2")
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 3")

        Dim excelFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo("test2.xlsx")

        OutputTextBlock.Text = excelFile.ToString()

        excel.SaveAs(excelFile)

        Process.Start(excelFile.ToString())
```

The errors are

*'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll*

*'System.InvalidOperationException' in EPPlus.dll*

How can I resolve it?

---

**UPDATE**

Example of a path which works when saving using the FileSavePicker:

```
        OutputTextBlock.Text = ""
        Dim savePicker As FileSavePicker = New FileSavePicker()
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", New List(Of String)() From {
            ".txt"
        })
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document"
        Dim file As StorageFile = Await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()

        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file)
            Await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Example file contents.")
            Dim status As FileUpdateStatus = Await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file)

            If status = FileUpdateStatus.Complete Then
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " was saved."
            ElseIf status = FileUpdateStatus.CompleteAndRenamed Then
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " was renamed and saved."
            Else
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " couldn't be saved."
            End If
        Else
            OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled."
        End If
```

Comment: Have you made sure that it is saving the file somewhere that the (account running the) program has write access to? E.g. the directory given by `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`? (Other folders are listed at [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8).)

Comment: Every directory in C:/ give this error.. if I save in another disk (e.g. D:/) it workes. But if I try to use FileSavePicker the app workes (save in C:/)

Comment: When you use `New FileInfo("test2.xlsx")`, it refers to a file in the same directory as the program. The program is not allowed to write their (it is an anti-malware feature). Does it work with `Dim excelFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test2.xlsx")`?

Comment: Or perhaps it needs to be `Dim excelFile = New FileInfo(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test2.xlsx"))`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you give an example of a path which works when saving using the FileSavePicker? Perhaps it corresponds to one of the Environment.SpecialFolder values.

Comment: I update the question